# Почему не работает ctrl+v в терминале Mingw

Tags: git, git-bash

Почему у меня не работает <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> в git?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы у меня здесь работала функция <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>?

Update:Окей ребят я понял что <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd> я не хочу т.к это только в этой проге и капец как не удобно как перекодить файл? (когда я пытаюсь его изменить мне пишет приложение не является Win32 (у меня 64bit))

Update2:Окей скорее всего у меня не та версия я прав?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня версия как у тебя всё-ровно нет такой настройки смотрел как в git bash так и в git cmd

Comment: ПКМ - твой выход

Comment: Я хочу клавиатуру использовать т.к пока я с клавы рукой до мышки дотянусь относительно много времени пройдёт для того чтобы просто вставить текст

Comment: Мне бы ваши проблемы... ):

Comment: Shift + Insert попробуйте

Comment: Ответ под win, надеюсь под линь примерно такой же принцип -_-

Comment: https://unfuddle.com/stack/tips-tricks/git-how-to-paste-in-git-bash/

Comment: Используйте консоль powershell, там ctrl+v работает, как обычно

Comment: Причём тут вообще гит, если проблема с консольным окном?

Answer (score 2):

1. ПКМ.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>
3. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Вроде как все возможные способы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста какая у тебя версия git у меня просто нет такой настройки

Comment: @nevazno1241 в `git bash` или `git cmd` смотрите эту настройку?

Comment: @nevazno1241, в ответе отправил

Comment: У меня всё-ровно не функционирует ctrl+v в программе git CMD и git Bash (у меня windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

Присоеденяюсь к тому что написал
@tomato-magnet-regulato

От себя добавлю что скорее всего из-за того что у меня windows 7
Также может быть из за того что автор проги решил не парится и не делать возможность ctrl+c ctrl+v